# @OneToMany unknown target entity property, with several @ManyToOne in children Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a error with Hibernate:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference 
an unknown target entity property: ch.zkb.documenz.backend.model.Template.user 
in ch.zkb.documenz.backend.model.User.templates
```

I have two Tables: User and Template, but in Template I need to use the id of the user in: createdBy, lockBy or lastUpdateBy, I think I have to use the @onetomany like in my example, but something it's incorrect, What is the best practice to do this then?

```
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
private Set<Template> templates;


public class Template implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "template_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "createdBy")
private User createdBy;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "lastUpdateBy")
private User lastUpdateBy;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "lockBy")
private User lockBy;
```

**EDIT**, I have now a Problem with the Bidirectional LAZY load, I want to get the user wo created the template but I can't.. always is NULL, but in the DB is stored properly

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "createdBy")
    private Set<Template> createdTemplates;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "createdBy", referencedColumnName = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User createdBy;
```

Answer (score 0):

You schould map to your private keys seperately, then in an transient method you can merge them.

```
private Set<Template> templates = new HasSet<Template>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "createdBy")
private Set<Template> createdByTemplates;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "lastUpdateBy")
private Set<Template> lastUpdateByTemplates;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "lockBy")
private Set<Template> lockByTemplates;

@Transient
public Set<Template> getTemplates(){
   if(getCreatedByTemplates() != null){
     templates.addAll(getCreatedByTemplates());
   }

   if(getLockByTemplates() != null){
     templates.addAll(getLockByTemplates());
   }

   if(getLastUpdateByTemplates() != null){
     templates.addAll(getLastUpdateByTemplates());
   }

   return templates;
}
```

Comment: sgpalit, now I can^t load in LAZY mode the createdBY from Template entity, you can see the code in the main question, in EDIT section, I have not Exception or Error..

Answer (score 0):

The exception message is clear about what doesn't work, the mappedBy must refer to the attribute name that you do have in the other entity,
in your Template entity there's no attribute named "user", try to remove the mappedBy.

Comment: Thanks winmiden, you are right, but now I have a problem with the LAZY LOAD, in my post you can see my new mapping, do you know here is the problem, I have no error, only the User Entity is NULL

Answer (score 0):

I believe mapped by is looking for bean name "user" in Template.

```
public class User implements Serializable {
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
private Set<Template> templates;


public class Template implements Serializable {
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
```

Change is variable name ***createdby to user in Template Class*** would help

Comment: thanks for the Help, I did like you told me but now I have a problem with the LAZY load, when I want to get the User createdBy, always is NULL, where is the problem?

Comment: Are you fetching "User" Parent or "Template" Child?